# Scheme pattern matching

Tags: scheme, design-patterns, racket, matching

I have written the following syntax rule:

```
(define-syntax match-rewriter  
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (patt body) ...)
     (λ (x) (match x (patt body) ... (_ x))))))
```

which is essentially `match-lambda` except that it returns its argument if no match is found rather than throwing an exception.

Now I want to write a function, `let_as_lambda`, that will take strings of source code as input and rewrite the `let` statements as the new `let_as_lambda` function.  This is what I have:

```
(define let_as_lambda  
  (match-rewriter (`(let((,<var> ,<val>)) ... ,<expressions>)
                   `((lambda (,<var> ...) ,<expressions>) ,<val> ...))))
```

It is clearly wrong as:

```
(let_as_lambda '(let((x 3)) (+ x 2)))
```

returns:

```
'((λ ((x) ...) (+ x 2)) (3) ...)
```

still showing the ellipses and with the "3" in parentheses.  I believe my problem is that I don't understand the proper usage of the symbols `` ` ``, `.`, and `,` in pattern matching.

If someone could show me the correct way to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably confused because you use two different pattern matching tools.  The first is what you get with `syntax-rules` and the second is `match`.  They seem close enough but there are some important differences -- and in this case, the main problem is that unlike `syntax-rules`, you cannot use `...` in quasi-quoted results of a `match`.  So to deal with lists of matched values you need to use `unquote-splicing` (or `,@`) and other functions like `map` etc.  For example, compare the results of these two expressions:

```
(match '(1 2 3) [`(,x ...) `(foo ,x ...)])
(match '(1 2 3) [`(,x ...) `(foo ,@x)])
```

As a side note, it would be nice if the usual `quasi-quote` would do what you want, but for a complete solution it needs to be possible with simple functions too -- and that complicates the whole thing (uses of `...` will need to translate to `apply`).

Comment: Dang! I was writing mine. You're just too fast, Eli. And your comment about the feasibility of adding "..." to quasiquote makes yours better than mine would have been, too. As my students would write:  >O